# find design patterns from a UML diagram?

Tags: design-patterns, uml

This is part of the java AWT package: [image: http://i.imgur.com/e3LVgUO.png]

- It looks like container is a decorator pattern, where container is the decorator, the panel and window subclasses are concrete decorators, the decorator has a pointer to component, and the textField & textArea are concrete components.
- another one I think would be the template method pattern, between TextComponent, TextField, and TextArea
- I want to say that LayoutManager is an abstract factory, but I am not 100% sure.  LayoutManager is the interface that defines different layouts which are pushed onto the Component.. maybe observer pattern?

I what I think correct? apparently there are others too, however I can't find what they are

Comment: Is this homework? Also, design patterns are more than just structure. They have context (the problem they solve) and behavior (the dynamics of calls when they're implemented). Much of this doesn't come from a class diagram only.

Comment: Several hints can be found here: http://www.soberit.hut.fi/tik-76.278/group6/awtpat.html

Comment: See the comments here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/233709/find-design-patterns-from-a-uml-diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LayoutManagers are the Strategy Pattern. I don't see how a container is a Decorator. If anything I would think it would be a Composite but it doesn't look like that either. A Decorator is an impostor: it presents itself as another type and then augments the original.